# .Net MVC How to split web app to 2 server architecture (web & app servers)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, n-tier-architecture

I have been deploying a .net web app to a single web server with a separate DB back-end server. What are the options if I am asked to separate this single web server into a web and app server? Is this a code change, a server setting change, or both? Any specific examples on deployment and not just theory (I get the theory already) on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A **Web Server** is where your webpages are hosted. Here will be all your HTML pages or the UI part.

Your Back-End and Database part will be on **Application Server**. Here, all the business logic, database transaction, schedules, windows services will be.

You can establish communication with your app server to your web server by using **HTTP Requests**.

These links can be useful to you:

1. [Restful API](https://restfulapi.net/)
2. [Web API](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/what-is-web-api)
3. [N-Tier Architecture](https://www.guru99.com/n-tier-architecture-system-concepts-tips.html)